# PHP: Return 404 header, but don't log in Apache's error log

Tags: php, apache

I have a lot of 404 errors (they are expected) and they are filling up my Apache error log, preventing me from finding the real errors. The 404 header is set by PHP. How can I send a 404 header to the client without having Apache log it?

If possible, I want Apache to still log real 404 errors (ones that aren't set by PHP).

Comment: Well, they *are* real.

Comment: I don't think you should be trying to differentiate the two that way. You would be better off changing the response of your expected 404's to something non 404.

Comment: Do you want that the request doesn't show at all in logs or that it shows up with a fake status code? What's your Apache version? Do you run PHP as Apache module or with some other SAPI?

Comment: I don't want it to show up at all in any logs. It's Apache 2.2 and it's running PHP as a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have PHP set a `header`

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

You can still send anything you want but the status will be 404 so spiders and such will ignore it.

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now, but Apache is still logging them.